# how to find vendor id of Android device

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

I have learned that I could use `lsusb` command to find *VendorId* of a USB device. But when I run this command on my system it is not giving me the *VendorId* of my tablet (Micromax P250 Funbook):

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 0d8c:000c C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. Optical Mouse M90
```

I have already enabled *USB Debugging* in the *Developer Options*.

Please help me to connect P250 micromax tablet with ADB on ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

1. Unplug the tablet
2. run `$ lsusb > /tmp/unplugged`
3. Plug the tablet
4. run `$ lsusb > /tmp/plugged`
5. run `$ diff /tmp/*plugged`

The line printed out contains the vendor id of the tablet. If nothing is printed, then both files are the same, then the tablet has not beed detected so there's another problem.

Answer (score 0):

You [no longer need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34815769/1778421) to find out the *VendorID* of a device to make `adb` recognize it. Although `lsusb` still could be useful for troubleshooting.

Diego's answer helps to figure out which line of the `lsusb` output belongs to your *most recently plugged-in* device. But in your case none of them do. Your device is not being recognized not by *just* `adb` but your whole system. Which suggests that there is something wrong with either the USB cable or the device itself. It is too early for you to be concerned with `adb` - you need to get to the point where your device gets recognized by the operating system first.

You can try the following troubleshooting steps (in no particular order) while checking for the new USB enumerations:

- replace the cable
- reboot the device
- reset device to the factory settings

If none of those steps results in your system recognizing the device - I would suggest replacing the device.