# Launch ADB using custom config adb_usb.ini file

Tags: android, adb

Is it possible to launch ADB pointed at an adb_usb.ini file in a custom location instead of looking at the users .android folder?  I would like to be able to limit an embedded adb executable to only look for certain vid/pids and not interfere with potentially other copies of ADB on the computer (such as from having installed the android sdk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

recent versions of `adb` do not use `adb_usb.ini` any more. [Google has removed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/c66aed8%5E!/) the `USB VendorID` whitelisting feature. There was no option to change the location of the file per user while it was still being used.

Comment: This is exactly the information that I needed.  I updated my ADB version and it could immediately see our custom device with no need to update the adb_usb.ini file.  Thanks!