# Is there an updated comprehensive list of Android manufacturers USB vendor ids?

Tags: android, usb, adb, android-source

I am trying to identify whether a phone is connected to my pc using `lsusb`.

I have found [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-5.1.1_r38/adb/usb_vendors.c) list of usb vendors inside `adb`s code. But it seems that after Android 5.1.1 this list has moved somewhere else and I'm worried it's not up to date.

Is there an updated list inside the current AOSP source code or anywhere else?

Comment: it was a bad idea to begin with. Google admitted it and they removed it. do not repeat their mistake

Comment: So it's not moved? They are just not using the list anymore?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34815769/1778421

Comment: OK. That's great! Thank you! Is there another way you would try to identify that a phone is connected to the computer or not? (phone does not necessarily have usb debugging enabled).